# Castle Windsor and its own configuration file

Tags: inversion-of-control, web-config, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor for IoC, and have the configuration held in the `web.config`/`app.config`, using the following factory:

```
public static TYPE Factory(string component)
    {
        var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
        var service = windsorContainer.Resolve<TYPE>(component);

        if (service == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Unable to find container {0}", component));

        return service;
    }
```

and my `web.config` looking like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
  </configSections>
  <castle>
    <components>
      <component id="Data" service="Data.IData, Data" type="Data.DataService, Data"/>
    </components>
  </castle>
  <appSettings>.......
```

Which works fine, but I'd like to place the configuration for Castle Windsor in a file called `castle.config`. How do I do this?

Comment: Note that you're creating a new container every time you need to resolve a component. Not only is that **very** inefficient but you also lose features like lifestyle management that way. Instead, create a single container per application.

Comment: Please tell me you're calling this method `Factory` just once per lifetime of your application...

Comment: It is only called as part of the constructor of an WCF service, is that okay?

Comment: if it works for you, it's *technically* ok. But it's not good practice. 1) aim for one container per app. 2) your services should know nothing about Windsor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WindsorContainer will accept the name of the configuration file as a construction parameter:

> public WindsorContainer(string xmlFile)
>
> Summary: Initializes a new instance of
>   the Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer
>   class using a xml file to configure
>   it. Equivalent to the use of new
>   WindsorContainer(new
>   XmlInterpreter(xmlFile))

Your castle.config file would then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <components> ...
```